# Run a function at a specific time in java

Tags: java, function, time

I have a Java object, which, among its other aspects, has a list of Sql.Time objects , say

```
 Time[] list = new Time[5];
 list = ["10:00:00","11:30:00","4:00:00"];
```

I need a certain function to run at these times everyday

```
void fun(){
    //
    // Other actions
    //
    System.out.println("The time is now " + time);  
}
```

. How do I do that?

Just mentioning a name of the class and function will be of great help.

Comment: See [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Comment: Woah thanks. I'll look into it